# Entity Framework DB Model First

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I've created a fresh ASP.NET Web Forms model, with authentication pre built. I've then run through the following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878

and created an entity framework from my exisiting database.

Ok, so far so good, however, when i fire up the project and click Register, the user created is still being inserted into a local db in the App_Data folder.

Why is this, and how can I ensure that all new users are pooled / created in my own database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because your DbContext is using built-in connection string. You can specify which connectionstring from your web.config to use when you initialize it in constructor like so.

```
public class MainDataContext : DbContext
{
    public MainDataContext() : base("Name=NameOfConnectionString") { }

    // public DbSet ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change you **Default Connection String** at **Web.config/App.config** with credentials of your own database.

Hope following link will help you:

http://hgminerva.wordpress.com/2013/09/21/how-to-create-the-asp-net-membership-tables-in-your-own-database/

Comment: Bappi I followed your link but, and I can now see my connection string is pointing to my existing database, but I get the following error:


The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).